# The output of ceil() and floor() in C language is odd

Tags: c, math.h, floor, ceil

I am doing my homework to realize a C programe and during my work there is one step that I need to get the interger part of the double type numbers. So I choose ceil() or floor() in  to realize this. But the output is unpredictable and far from expected.

The whole program is the following :

```
 /*
 ************************************************************************
  Includes
 ************************************************************************
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Solvent Particle Propersities*/
typedef struct 
  {
    double vx,vy,rx,ry ;  /*  velocity AND position               */
    double    cell;                /*  index of grid  */
   }solvent_p;

  /* Cell Propersities*/
 typedef struct 
  {
  double vcm_x,vcm_y ;  /*  center of mass velocity  */
  int    number;        /*  number of solvent in the cell  */
  double roation_angle; /*  roation_angle of the cell */
  }cell_p;

/* periodic boundary condition judging and adjusting fuction PBC */

 void PBC(solvent_p *sol)
 {
  double L = 20.0;  // box size 20

  if(sol->rx >20) sol->rx=sol->rx-L;
  if(sol->rx < 0) sol->rx=sol->rx+L;
  if(sol->ry >20) sol->ry=sol->ry-L;
  if(sol->ry < 0) sol->ry=sol->ry+L;

 }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   // Randome setup generates random numbers from GSL functions 
   const gsl_rng_type * T;
   gsl_rng * r;
   T = gsl_rng_default;
   gsl_rng_default_seed = ((unsigned long)(time(NULL))); //设seed值为当前时间 
   r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);

   solvent_p solvent[4000];
   int i,j,k,index=0;
   cell_p grid[400];
   double alpha=90.0; //roation angle

  /*  Iniinitializing solvent  
   *  All vx=0
   *  half vy = sqrt(3) and half vy=-sqrt(3) to make momentum zero and another requirement is the overall energy is 6000 equals energy of temperature=1 with 4000 solvent 3NkT/2 ,assuming mass of solvent = 1 ,which is all a test quantity 
  *  rx and ry are random number generated by GSL library
  *  cell=20*(ry+rx) is an index of which cell the solvent is in
  */
  for(i=0;i<=3999;i++)
  {
         solvent[i].vx=0.0;

         if(i<=1999)
              solvent[i].vy=sqrt(3);
         else
              solvent[i].vy=-sqrt(3);


      solvent[i].rx =20.0 * gsl_rng_uniform_pos(r);

      solvent[i].ry =20.0 * gsl_rng_uniform_pos(r);

     //printf("%f \t %f \n",solvent[i].rx,solvent[i].ry);

    solvent[i].cell=20*(floor(solvent[i].ry))+floor(solvent[i].rx)+1;
    }

     // grid setting up
     for (i=0;i<=399;i++)
   {
        grid[i].vcm_x=0;
        grid[i].vcm_y=0;
        grid[i].number=0;
        grid[i].roation_angle=0.0;
   }


        /*  Begining Simulation Work
         * 
         *  Fist process is preparing the system to equilibrium for 10000 processes
          * 
          *  the whole process involving two steps steaming and collision and the two steps are conducted one by one in our simulation 
          *  time duration for steaming is 0.1 which is assigned for Molecular Dynamics and time duration for collision is ignored
          * 
          *  
          */


       for(i=0;i<=9999;i++)
 {
       double temp;
       double delta_t_MD=0.1; //time step

        temp=gsl_rng_uniform_pos(r);
        double rand_rx = (temp < 0.5) ? temp : ((-1) * temp ); // randomshift rx;

        temp=gsl_rng_uniform_pos(r);
        double rand_ry = (temp < 0.5) ? temp : ((-1) * temp ); // randomshift ry


       //steaming
      for(j=0;j<=3999;j++)
      {
            //printf("%d \n",j);
            printf("1 :%d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[j].ry);
            solvent[j].rx=solvent[j].rx+solvent[j].vx * delta_t_MD;
            solvent[j].ry=solvent[j].ry+solvent[j].vy * delta_t_MD;

            printf("2: %d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[j].ry);

    //randomshift
    solvent[j].rx=solvent[j].rx+rand_rx;
    solvent[j].ry=solvent[j].ry+rand_ry;
    printf("3:  %d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[j].ry);
    // periodic boundary condition
    PBC(&solvent[j]);
    printf("4: %d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[j].ry);
    solvent[j].cell=20*(ceil(solvent[j].ry)-1)+ceil(solvent[j].rx);
    printf("5: %d \t  %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[j].ry,ceil(solvent[j].rx),ceil(solvent[j].ry));
    index = (int)(solvent[j].cell);
    //printf("%d \t %d \t %f \t %f \t %f \n",j,index,solvent[j].cell,ceil(solvent[j].rx),ceil(solvent[j].ry));

    if ((index>=0) &&(index<=400))
    {
    grid[index].vcm_x=grid[index].vcm_x+solvent[i].vx;
    grid[index].vcm_y=grid[index].vcm_y+solvent[i].vy;
    grid[index].number=grid[index].number+1;
   }
}


// caculating vcm

for (k=0;k<=399;k++)
{
    if (grid[k].number >= 1)
    {
        grid[k].vcm_x=grid[k].vcm_x/grid[k].number;
        grid[k].vcm_y=grid[k].vcm_y/grid[k].number; 
    }

    double temp;
    temp=gsl_rng_uniform_pos(r);
    grid[k].roation_angle = (temp < 0.5) ? alpha : ((-1) * alpha ); 
}



//collsion


 }

gsl_rng_free (r); // free RNG

return 0;
```

}

Sorry it is some extent long so I did not put in first.And something did not finished but the program framework is set up.

my programe is like this:

```
    printf("4: %d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[i].ry);
    solvent[j].cell=20*(floor(solvent[j].ry))+floor(solvent[j].rx)+1;
    printf("5: %d \t  %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[i].ry,floor(solvent[j].rx),floor(solvent[j].ry));
```

And although something as I wanted something more is wrong and below is I choose some parts of the output:

```
4: 3993       3.851240   17.047031 
5: 3993       3.851240   17.047031   3.000000    9.000000
```

although floor(solvent[j].rx) is right but floor(solvent[j].ry) is totally wrong.

And the final result of my program is

```
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)


  ------------------
  (program exited with code: 139)
```

How to fix this one? Is there anything I use was wrong?

And to further test the problem I tried ceil() function in  and the program and result is like this

program:

```
    printf("4: %d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[i].ry);
    solvent[j].cell=20*(ceil(solvent[j].ry)-1)+ceil(solvent[j].rx);
    printf("5: %d \t  %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[i].ry,ceil(solvent[j].rx),ceil(solvent[j].ry));
```

result:

```
2: 3999       14.571205      2.837654 
4: 3999       14.571205      2.837654 
5: 3999       14.571205      2.837654    15.000000   15.000000
```

So use the nearest output as an example to illustrate my desire result is:

a= 14.571205, ceil(a)=15.00
b= 2.837654 , ceil(b)=3.00 not the 15.000 in the output

And the problem worsening is that when I just use a and b to test ceil() everything seems perfect:

program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main()
{
        double a= 14.571205;  
        double b= 2.837654 ;  

        printf("%f \t %f \n",ceil(a),ceil(b));
        return 0;
 }
```

output:
       15.000000     3.000000

I am using GCC in Linux Ubuntu.

==============================================================================

The problem has been solved.

The real fatal problem is here

```
    if ((index>=0) &&(index<=400))
    {
    grid[index].vcm_x=grid[index].vcm_x+solvent[i].vx;
    grid[index].vcm_y=grid[index].vcm_y+solvent[i].vy;
    grid[index].number=grid[index].number+1;
   }
}
```

Both `solvent[i].vy` and `solvent[i].vx` should be changed i for j.

Just as @Jon and @Blckknght @Eric Lippert have pointed out.

And I obvious get in the wrong trap and mislead @ouah and @Blckknght and In fact, the output sentences do have problem but they do not caused the prorame to crash only the out of boundary will do that.

Thank you ALL!

And I do like to share   Eric Lippert 's comment which is powerful and insightful:

> More generally, the problem you have is called "select isn't broken" by experienced programmers. That is, you have done something completely wrong, you cannot figure out what you did wrong, and so you conclude that a piece of basic, easy infrastructure written by experts and tested extensively is wrong. I assure you, floor and ceil do exactly what they are supposed to do. They are not wrong. The problem lies somewhere in your code, not in the standard library. –  Eric Lippert

[image: The final result]

Comment: Some of your code that manipulates the array is wrong and you end up reading outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Could you provide a real test case? How are `solvent` declared and what are the values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: Obtain a rubber duck or a teddy bear or other inanimate object.  **Read your program out loud to the duck**. Seriously. Read every line of it. If that doesn't find the bug, **explain every line to the duck, with a careful justification of why every single part of it is absolutely correct**. If you are unable to do this then either (1) you have written a program that is wrong, or (2) you don't understand the program you wrote. Either way, that's the thing you have to fix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're indexing with `i` where you should be using `j` (or perhaps vise versa).

Comment: More generally, the problem you have is called "select isn't broken" by experienced programmers. That is, you have done something completely wrong, you cannot figure out what you did wrong, and so you conclude that a piece of basic, easy infrastructure written by experts and tested extensively is wrong.  I assure you, `floor` and `ceil` do exactly what they are supposed to do.  They are not wrong. The problem lies somewhere in your code, not in the standard library.

Comment: `i ` and `j` are pretty easy to confuse. For example, in the first output, line "5:", you see that solvent[i].ry is 2.837654 while ceil(solvent[j].ry) is 15. There is no contradiction there unless i happens to be equal to j.

Comment: @ouah I put the whole codes.It is a physics programe.

Comment: @rici yeah. and I will check them more and output 4 and output 5 is where I concerned and I thought the problem is. But As many people has pointed out maybe I need to have a break and then think the problem from starting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is declared as:

```
solvent_p solvent[4000];
```

but you have this loop:

```
 for(i=0;i<=9999;i++)
```

with this function call inside:

```
 printf("1 :%d \t  %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[i].ry);
```

which means you are accessing out-of-bounds array elements.

**EDIT:**

OP test case has been edited to fix the out-of-bound accesses.

My second suggestion is to check `index` value (which is used to index `grid` array) never exceeds the number of elements of `grid` array after this assignment: `index = (int)(solvent[j].cell)`.

Comment: This is an outside loop who control the number of a whole process not a loop to travel the array 。

Comment: Yep,output 1 is something wrong but in fact they change little of the calculation and the main bug is that I could not get my expected integer part of the double part.

Thankyou, I changed output1

Comment: @sikisis it invokes undefined behavior and you have to fix this. Moreover `index` object is used to index `grid` array so you should add a condition to ensure in `index = (int)(solvent[j].cell)` that `index` never exceeds the nunber of elements of `grid`.

Comment: Yeah, I will make something to check the boundary of the `grid` arry

Comment: is this OK?  `if ((index>=0) &&(index<=400)){}` But the problem seems sticks on there.

But I have some thoughts I feel function  `void PBC(solvent_p *sol)` may be wrong.

Comment: `index < 400` not `<=`

Comment: yeah and this time I find that `1 :3992    11.753972   11.147211 
2: 3992    11.753972   10.974006 
4: 3992    11.753972   0.000000 
5: 3992    11.753972   0.000000   12.000000   11.000000 
`

Comment: `4: 3993    7.511782   1144434772136479726475766354784996059164401973333025433544530832140162811006000349447288225347890532183547119679624159139322493127058065260080099012090741383372459453210481581960228366173208303380938971750117520390258817818008554857424505274368.000000` something wrong between output2 and output4

Comment: However it seems like a minor mistake and can not produce some many trouble. And I am sure that ceil() and floor is nothing wrong, So I must have make mistake in choose the index of the array and someplace when wrong. @ouah Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the issue is with the indexes you're using. In the statement in question:

```
printf("5: %d \t  %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n",j,solvent[j].rx,solvent[i].ry,floor(solvent[j].rx),floor(solvent[j].ry));
```

you are printing the `ry` value of `solvent[i]` but the floor of the `ry` value of `solvent[j]`. I suspect that you want to be using the same index in both places (though I'm not sure which index you want).

Comment: OH, thank you, I have solved the problem and the out of boundary problem is really fatal to my programe.